# Return a class with ngModule metadata

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm trying to write a re-usable class for setting up an ngModule.

The class looks like this:

```
export class IncludeServerApp {
  constructor(AppComponent: any, AppModule: any) { 
    return @NgModule({
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: APP_BOOTSTRAP_LISTENER,
          useFactory: onBootstrap,
          multi: true,
          deps: [
            ApplicationRef,
            TransferState
        }
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule.withServerTransition({
          appId: 'my-app-id'
        }),
        ServerModule,
        ServerTransferStateModule,
        AppModule
      ]
    })
    class ServerAppModule { }
    }
  }
}
```

I then use the class like so:

```
new IncludeServerApp(AppComponent, AppModule)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
  Error: No NgModule metadata found for '[object Object]'.
      at NgModuleResolver.resolve (/Users/michael/Code/ng-universal-demo/dist/server.js:73337:23)
      at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (/Users/michael/Code/ng-universal-demo/dist/server.js:73921:60)
      at JitCompiler._loadModules (/Users/michael/Code/ng-universal-demo/dist/server.js:85088:66)
      at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (/Users/michael/Code/ng-universal-demo/dist/server.js:85047:52)
      at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (/Users/michael/Code/ng-universal-demo/dist/server.js:85009:23)
      at Promise (/Users/michael/Code/ng-universal-demo/dist/server.js:112849:22)
      at new ZoneAwarePromise (/Users/michael/Code/ng-universal-demo/dist/server.js:151252:29)
      at getFactory (/Users/michael/Code/ng-universal-demo/dist/server.js:112835:12)
      at View.engine (/Users/michael/Code/ng-universal-demo/dist/server.js:112813:13)
      at View.render (/Users/michael/Code/ng-universal-demo/dist/server.js:116553:8)
```

From what I am seeing, Webpack is removing the `@ngModule` code after compiling for some reason. Is this actually possible to do? I understand that @ngModule is used to give metadata for the `ServerAppModule` class I'm trying to return.

I've noticed if I have the return before the @ngModule the error is:

```
Error: No NgModule metadata found for '[object Object]'
```

if it is before the `class ServerAppModule {}` the error is:

```
Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'ServerAppModule'.
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know it should work, just be aware that you will not have AOT functionality, which will give your application a big boost. So, you should have a really good reason doing things like this.

Anyways, my guess is that you need to switch your parameters :) and create a static method, because your class expects a component first, and then a module, not the other way around

```
IncludeServerApp.createServerApp(AppComponent, AppModule)
```

And move your return:

```
export class IncludeServerApp {

  static createServerApp(appComponent, appModule) {
     @NgModule({...})
     class ServerAppModule {}

     return ServerAppModule ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the AOT tip. Sorry the params was a typo, I also missed the return in the constructor. I've noticed if I have the return before the @ngModule the error is ```Error: No NgModule metadata found for '[object Object]'```, if its before the ```class ServerAppModule {}``` the error is ```Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'ServerAppModule'.```

Comment: Yes, the return is on the wrong position. You should place it below I believe. Ill update my answer. And you cannot return a different thing from a constructor. You should add an extra method, or use a static method

Comment: that fixed that error, but now I am getting it about the AppModule - ```Error: Unexpected value 'AppModule' imported by the module 'ServerAppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.```

Comment: Does the class `AppModule` have an `@NgModule` annotation?

Comment: Yes it does... I wonder if its an issue passing ```AppModule``` through to ```createServerApp()```